# как сделать эффект grayscale

Tags: css, hover, img

Можно ли как-то  сделать эффект такой же как на этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ccwzz09WaYU , но только без дублирования картинки?

Comment: Это два блока с `position:abcolute;`  снизу черно-белая картинка,  и при `hover`,  верхний слой расширяется, цветная картинка

Comment: Эм... Там же в видео все расписано?

Comment: да, но там есть 1 картинка, которая дублируется, мне надо, чтобы картинка не дублировалась, а эффект оставался.

Comment: Ты хочешь чтобы была одна картинка и сама картинка так менялась?

Comment: да, нужно с одной картинкой, если это возможно

Comment: Ну тогда `canvas`... но боюсь, что это будет слишком громоздко....

Comment: А можно как-то искусственно сделать эффект grayscale, через background + opacity ?

Comment: Дима, ты лучше вопрос опиши нормально, выложи `html && css` опиши вопрос подробно. Вопрос должен содержать код, проблему и желанный конечный результат... А то играем, словами... ты хочешь обойтись точно такого результата как в видео и обойтись только одним слоем? А `background + opacity` тут при чем?

Comment: В общем, что надо, есть картинка, у которой по дефолту grayscale(100%), при наведении, grayscale исчезает как на видео.
При этом надо сделать без дублирования картинки.

Comment: а по поводу background + opacity, была мысль просто сделать через :after.
Например
img:after{
background: gray;
opacity: .5;
left:0;
}
img:after:hover{
left: 100%
}

Comment: данного эффекта как на видео простым `css` не добиться.... можно использовать псевдо-элементы ты прав, но это будет все же второй слой...  который формирует `css`... и не надо ни какого `opacity` ...  Если  конечно хочешь именно такого результата...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Целиком как на видео делать поленился, могли бы код минимальный сделать. Остальное по примеру доделаете.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.effect {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://images.yoins.com/thumb/big/oaupload/yoins/images/78/22/0e91e46a-b33c-45a8-8d0a-fd3f74a86dc3.jpg) no-repeat right center / cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.effect:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: All 1s ease;
  -o-transition: All 1s ease;
  transition: All 1s ease;
}

.effect:hover:before {
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="effect"></div>
```

Comment: только из за фотки я удалил - жесть + от меня

Comment: @МаксимЛенский зря удалил. Вариант с использованием JS тоже актуальный, если в разметке будет не `background` у блока, а `<img>`.

Comment: думаешь восстановить стоит ?

Comment: Любой ответ будет полезным

Comment: я восстановил уже

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, ну совсем нет совести... Ну можно такие фото выставлять...)))

Comment: @Air  нормальное фотка

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Макс, ну я же не сказал, что не нормальное фото)))

Comment: Нужно совмещать приятное с полезным)